# CLLocation 'coordinate' is unavailable

Tags: ios, swift, cllocation

I have an issue using getting lat and long from a CLLocation object.

The weird thing is, up until yesterday I was able to retrieve the lat and long by doing:

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!) {

    var location: AnyObject? = locations.last

    if let location: AnyObject = location {
        //The println illustrates how I would retrieve the lat and long, i.e. by calling
        //location.coordinate.latitude.

        println(location.coordinate.latitude)

        locationDelegate?.updateLabels(location)
        self.locationsArray.append(location)
    }
}
```

This has now stopped working and it throws me the following compiler error:

[image]

If i remove the `.coordinate` call and call `.latitude` directly on the `location` object, it just returns `nil`. I'm a bit lost as to whats going on here...

if I `println(location)` i get the following output:

```
<+56.92239472,+1.47020887> +/- 5.00m (speed -1.00 mps / course -1.00) @ 10/11/14, 2:37:59 PM British Summer Time
```

Can anybody help me understand whats going on and how to retrieve the lat and long again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateToLocation newLocation: CLLocation!, fromLocation oldLocation: CLLocation!)`instead of the above delegate method and then calling `newLocation.coordinate.latitude` seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem. The proper solution is to cast the location objects to CLLocation before you dereference the coordinate property. The following code should work, although I haven't actually tested it. Additionally, there may be a more elegant way to do the cast; I'm still learning Swift myself.

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager!, didUpdateLocations locations: [AnyObject]!) {

   var location: AnyObject? = locations.last

   if let location: AnyObject = location {
       //The println illustrates how I would retrieve the lat and long, i.e. by calling
       //location.coordinate.latitude.
       var loc = location as CLLocation
       println(loc.coordinate.latitude)

       locationDelegate?.updateLabels(loc)
       self.locationsArray.append(loc)
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to implement this method is to define the coordinates.  (i assume you trying to get the current location)

```
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {

            if !isCurrentLocation {
                return
            }

            isCurrentLocation = false

            let location = locations.last

// here define the center variable to hold the coordinates for reuse!
            let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location!.coordinate.latitude, longitude: location!.coordinate.longitude)
            let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: center, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: DesiredLocation.latitude, longitudeDelta: DesiredLocation.longitude))


            self.mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)


    }
```

And its all set!